# MacBook 12" mirroring on iMac

Tags: macos, mac, mirroring

I have an old MacBook Air, which, when using Thunderbolt cable, I am able to mirror the screen on my iMac.

However, I cannot do the same for my newer MacBook 12".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that under `System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement` (this tab *only* shows up **if your computer detects an external display**), the "Mirror Displays" checkbox at the bottom is checked.

This checkbox determines whether your secondary display will act as an "extension" or as a mirror of your primary.

Comment: What I mean is that there is no cabling that allows this and not a software related problem.

Comment: There might be external third party USB-C to VGA, or USB-C to Thunderbolt (which you can adapt to Thunderbolt to VGA)

Comment: still does not make me see from the macbook 12 inch on the imac